# Azure WebSite Grant Access

Tags: windows, azure, web-applications

I want to allow a user to access the Azure using the Server Explorer in Visual Studio, so I tried to add a user in portal.azure.com, in the web app > users > add user, and he is added as a contributor.

But when he tries to access in the Server Explorer, he is not granted to. The only way I could allow him to sign in is to access the manage.windowsazure.com and add him as a co-admin, and I definitively don't want him to have that much access.

How can I give him contributor rights only in the web app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have started with the correct way - granting **Contributor** role for that Web App (Website) to the particular user.

Next thing he has to do is:

1. Login to the https://portal.azure.com
2. Browse to that web site
3. Set Deployment Credentials:
   [image]
4. Use the deployment Credentials to connect via FTP

Read more on Deployment Credentials here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials (Project KUDU is what Azure Web Apps run on)

Last, but not least, once he has Contributor Role for the Web App, he can also use Visual Studio Online Monaco to edit the content on the web site: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/monaco/archive/2014/06/26/how-to-access-visual-studio-online-monaco-from-the-new-azure-portal.aspx

Note: He still won't be able to access the site via Server Explorer, but he will be able to access it via FTP and via the Kudu Console and will be able to download Publishing Profile - all he needs to manage the content of that Web App.

Comment: Thanks, this works. The issue is that the Server Explorer tool from Visual Studio is not supported yet using this users control.